# xalan validation java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function

Tags: java, validation, xslt, xalan

I try to validate data in my page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:item="http://www.myspace.com/item"
    xmlns:shop="xalan://my.app.xslt.model.Shop" xmlns:valid="xalan://my.app.xslt.validation.ShopValidator"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
```

I have a model with field, and class validator with methods for checking every field.

And in row

```
<xsl:if test="valid:isNotEmptyData(shop:getOwner($item)) != true()">
            <error message="The field OWNER is empty." />
        </xsl:if>
```

I get NoSuchMethodExtension although I have in model

```
public class Shop{
  private String owner;
  public String getOwner(){
    return owner;
  }
}
```

And in validator class

```
public static boolean isNotEmptyData(String model){
  retutn model.isEmpty();
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `Shop.getOwner()` has no arguments, whereas in the XSLT you call it as `shop:getOwner($item))` with one argument - the XSLT processor looks for a method with one argument and cannot find it, hence the error.

I am not sure what `getOwner()` is supposed to do - possibly to extract some value from its arguments..? In such a case you should modify it to accept an argument and process it.

By the way,

```
valid:isNotEmptyData(shop:getOwner($item)) != true()
```

can be written using standard XPath functions as

```
 not(string(shop:getOwner($item)))
```

(a string is considered true if it is non-empty), or as

```
string-length(shop:getOwner($item)) = 0
```

Comment: I have a new question on the same theme. I add it above. ( in current question)